# Neural-net Regression predicts same value for all test samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, keras

My **neural-network regression model predicts one value for all the test samples**. Playing with hyperparameters like epochs, batch_size, number of layers, hidden units, learning rate, etc. only changes the prediction values to a new constant.

For testing, if I test on the training data itself, I get almost accurate results and a RMSE ~ 1.

Note: The task is to predict remaining life of a machine from its run-till-failure time series data. I have used tsfresh library to generate 1045 features from the original time series data with only 24 features.

***What should be causing this behavior? How should I visualize a neural network model development to make sure things are going in the right direction?***

```
print "Shape of training_features is", train_X.shape
print "Shape of train_labels is", train_Y.shape
print "Shape of test_features is", test_X.shape
print "shape of test_labels is", test_Y.shape

input_dim = train_X.shape[1]
# Function to create model, required for KerasRegressor
def create_model(h1=50, h2=50, act1='sigmoid', act2='sigmoid', init='he_normal', learn_rate=0.001, momentum=0.1, loss='mean_squared_error'):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(h1, input_dim=input_dim, init=init, activation=act1))
    model.add(Dense(h2, init=init, activation=act2))
    model.add(Dense(1, init=init))
    # Compile model
    optimizer = SGD(lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

''' THE REAL THING '''
# create model
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

# SCORING FUNCTION
grid_scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)
# Grid Search
batch_size = [8]
epochs = [500]
init_mode = ['glorot_uniform']
learn_rate = [0.0001]
momentum = [0.1]

hidden_layer_1 = [75]
activation_1 = ['sigmoid']
hidden_layer_2 = [15]
activation_2 = ['sigmoid']

param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=epochs, init=init_mode, h1=hidden_layer_1, h2=hidden_layer_2, act1 = activation_1, act2=activation_2, learn_rate=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)

print "\n...BEGIN SEARCH..."
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring=grid_scorer, verbose=1)

print "\nLet's fit the training data..."
grid_result = grid.fit(train_X, train_Y)

# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))

predicted = grid.predict(test_X)  
print "\nPrediction array is\n", predicted
rmse = numpy.sqrt(((predicted - test_Y) ** 2).mean(axis=0))
print "Test RMSE is", rmse
```

Output:

```
Shape of training_features is (249, 1045)
Shape of train_labels is (249,)
Shape of test_features is (248, 1045)
shape of test_labels is (248,)

...BEGIN SEARCH...

Let's fit the training data...
Fitting 5 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 5 fits
Best: -891.761863 using {'learn_rate': 0.0001, 'h2': 15, 'act1': 'sigmoid', 'act2': 'sigmoid', 'h1': 75, 'batch_size': 8, 'init': 'glorot_uniform', 'nb_epoch': 500, 'momentum': 0.1}
-891.761863 (347.253351) with: {'learn_rate': 0.0001, 'h2': 15, 'act1': 'sigmoid', 'act2': 'sigmoid', 'h1': 75, 'batch_size': 8, 'init': 'glorot_uniform', 'nb_epoch': 500, 'momentum': 0.1}

Prediction array is
[ 295.72067261  295.72067261  295.72067261  295.72067261  295.72067261
  295.72067261  295.72067261  ...
                              295.72067261  295.72067261  295.72067261
  295.72067261  295.72067261  295.72067261]
Test RMSE is 95.0019297411
```

Comment: So you use 249 samples with 1045 features to train a neural network? This may lead to serious overfitting. I'd suggest you get more data or reduce the number of features.

Comment: I don't think I have a way to get more data (research project). But the question is "why should overfit model be predicting all the values same"? Should it not be giving bad/random, maybe, but different values for different test feature vectors?

Comment: Try changing either `activations` to `relu` or `initializer` to `glorot_normal`. `he_normal` is for `relu`. Using `sigmoid` is considered to be not the best idea - you could suffer from vanishing gradients - especially when you initialized `sigmoid` with `he` and your `lr` and `momentum` are so small.

Comment: I think I have tried these combinations as well. But, i will report again after trying more with your suggestions. What I am doing is mostly empirical, hit & trial; I wish I could visualize how things are unfolding beneath. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try scaling your data.  This normally happens when features are not scaled.